# Check readiness endpoint state in Apigee HealthMonitor

Tags: spring, apigee

I'm trying to setup Apigee proxy which would loadbalance between two target servers. For servers health check I created and exposed default spring boot health endpoint, but I fail to follow or find in Apigee official docs if it is possible to check payload or body returned by the health endpoints.
https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/deploy/load-balancing-across-backend-servers

Also tried to use Response code which works, but I want to check if health endpoint would return specifically status UP, as it technically can be with the status DOWN.

**Health endpoint response body:**
`{"status":"UP"}`

**Health monitor:**

```
<HealthMonitor>
  <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
  <IntervalInSec>5</IntervalInSec>
  <HTTPMonitor>
    <Request>
      <ConnectTimeoutInSec>10</ConnectTimeoutInSec>
      <SocketReadTimeoutInSec>30</SocketReadTimeoutInSec>
      <Port>8080</Port>
      <Verb>GET</Verb>
      <Path>/health/readiness</Path>
    </Request>
    <SuccessResponse>
      <ResponseCode>200</ResponseCode>
      <Payload>{"status":"UP"}</Payload>
    </SuccessResponse>
  </HTTPMonitor>
</HealthMonitor>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Apigee's [ExtractVariables policy](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/extract-variables-policy#json) to inspect your Health Monitor's response body and extract the key status variable for use in your logic, perhaps in a custom JS policy which uses the extracted variable to affect your load-balancing.

See also:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j719pLh76vg

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but I'm lost how would I apply it to the SuccessResonse in the HTTPMonitor, as far as I understand I would need to do hacky stuff right?

Comment: Thinking about it more, your HTTPMonitor and direct inspection with <Payload> should work within the HealthMonitor. Does it not work? If so, maybe a syntax issue? Docs are lean, but Apigee Support should be able to give you more examples and clarification. https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/deploy/load-balancing-across-backend-servers#healthmonitoring-httpmonitor

Otherwise a more custom solution would be to use a service callout policy in your proxy to call the health endpoint, and use ExtractVariables to process its results.